# Export functions which returns a reference

Tags: c++, python, boost, reference, export

I want to export into python module (written in c++, with boost.python library) such function:

```
Vec2<Type> &normalize () 
Type dot(const Vec2<Type> &vector) const
```

These are the members of template class `Vec2`. Here is my export code:

```
bp::class_< Vec2<int> >("Vec2i", bp::init<int, int>())
    .def("Length", &Vec2<int>::length)
    .def("Dot", &Vec2<int>::dot, bp::return_internal_reference<>());
    //.def("Normalize", &Vec2<int>::normalize);
```

`Length` method compiles successful, but `Dot` and `Normalize` returns same mistake (during compiling):

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::python::class_<Vec2<int> >::def(const char [4], <unresolved overloaded function type>, boost::python::return_internal_reference<>)’
```

What I did wrong?

---

**UPD**

The real class name is: `CL_Vec<Type>`, here is the [docs](http://clanlib.org/docs/clanlib-2.2/reference_doxygen/classCL__Vec2.html).

Comment: Since these are apparently member functions, please show the whole class definition.

Comment: Is there an additional overload of `dot` that you aren't showing us?

Comment: @larsmans @john-zwinck I've added to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [`vec2.h`](http://clanlib.org/docs/clanlib-2.2/reference_doxygen/vec2_8h_source.html) (or the docs you link to), you'll see that `dot` and `normalize` are both overloaded, since there also exist `static` versions of these.

You can get around this by using a few function pointers:

```
Vec2<int> &(Vec2<int>::*norm)() = &Vec2<int>::normalize;
```

and then using that in the `def`, as explained [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/functions.html#python.overloading).

Comment: @Ockonal: `dot` is a `const` method, which must be reflected in the function pointer's type.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I understand my problem.

Comment: @Ockonal: no need to apologize!

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler says:

```
<unresolved overloaded function type>
```

Take a look at your pointer-to-member or function pointer (&Vec2::dot) and see if it refers to a set of overload functions (it should).  In this case you may need an explicit static_cast<> to the specific pointer-to-member or function pointer type, including function parameter types.

Comment: Looking at the docs, there's another function for both normalize and dot - although both of them are static.

Comment: Interesting... since the &CLASS::FUNCTION syntax is valid for static too (though it makes the & unnecessary and due to that I like to leave it out in my code), the compiler can't tell which one you want.  Same principle applies even though it's not actually a pointer-to-member.